# Help in "commutator expansion" containing creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I am trying to expand the commutator $\left[ {{H_0},S} \right]$ to get the ${H_1}$ according to the equation:
$${H_1} = {H_I} + \left[ {{H_0},S} \right],$$
where,
$${H_I} = {g_k}\left[ {\left( {{b_k} + b_k^\dagger } \right){\sigma ^ + } + h.c.} \right],$$
$${H_0} = \left( {{\omega _k}b_k^\dagger{b_k} + {\Omega  \over 2}{\sigma _z}} \right),$$
$$S = \left( {{A_k}b_k^\dagger{\sigma ^ + } - {A_k}{b_k}{\sigma ^ - }} \right),$$
where ${b_k^\dagger }$, ${b_k}$ are the creation and annihilation operators, ${\sigma _{x,y,z}}$ are the Pauli operators I reach to:
$${H_1} = {H_I} + {H_0}S - S{H_0},$$
with:
$${H_0}S = {\omega _k}{A_k}b_k^\dagger{b_k}b_k^\dagger{\sigma ^ + } - {A_k}{\omega _k}b_k^\dagger{b_k}{b_k}{\sigma ^ - } + {\Omega  \over 2}{A_k}{\sigma _z}b_k^\dagger{\sigma ^ + } - {\Omega  \over 2}{A_k}{\sigma _z}{b_k}{\sigma ^ - },$$
$$S{H_0} = {A_k}{\omega _k}b_k^\dagger\sigma b_k^\dagger{b_k} + {A_k}{\Omega  \over 2}b_k^\dagger\sigma {\sigma _z} - {A_k}{\omega _k}{b_k}{\sigma ^ - }b_k^\dagger{b_k} - {A_k}{\Omega  \over 2}{b_k}{\sigma ^ - }{\sigma _z}$$
But I failed to simplify the result as in the [original search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Quantum%20anti-Zeno%20effect%20without%20rotating%20wave%20approximation&btnG=), where:
$${H_1} = {g_k}\left( {{b_k} + b_k^\dagger} \right){\sigma ^ + } + {A_k}\left( {{\omega _k} + \Omega } \right)b_k^\dagger{\sigma ^ + } + h.c.$$
I expect thet he used some kind of relations to get this simplified form. Please help with this simple problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have :
\begin{align}
[H_0,S] &= \left [ \omega_k b^\dagger_k b_k + \frac{\Omega}{2}\sigma_z, A_kb_k^\dagger \sigma^+ - A_kb_k\sigma^-\right]\\
&=\omega_kA_k\left[b_k^\dagger b_k,b_k^\dagger\sigma^+-b_k\sigma^-\right] + \frac{A_k\Omega}{2}\left[\sigma_z,b_k^\dagger \sigma^+ - b_k\sigma^-\right]
\end{align}

Now, we can use :
\begin{align}
\left[b_k,b_k^\dagger\right] &= 1 \\
\left[b_k,\sigma^+\right]&= \left[b_k,\sigma^-\right] = \left[b_k,\sigma_z\right] = 0 \\
\left[b_k^\dagger,\sigma^+\right]&= \left[b_k^\dagger,\sigma^-\right] = \left[b_k^\dagger,\sigma_z\right] = 0 \\
[\sigma_z,\sigma^+] &= 2\sigma^+\\
[\sigma_z,\sigma^-] &= -2\sigma^-
\end{align}
to get :
$$[H_0,S] = \omega_k A_k b_k^\dagger \sigma^+ + \omega_k A_kb_k\sigma^- + {A_k\Omega}(b^\dagger_k \sigma^+ + b_k\sigma^-) = A_k(\omega_k + \Omega)b_k^\dagger\sigma^+ + \text{h.c}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. You really helped me a lot